# React Native Android hybrid App - Detox hangs after launching app, hits jest timeout

Tags: android, react-native, hybrid, detox

I'm trying Detox in a Hybrid React Native App. Most of the app has been moved to React but the are some screen still on Android.
**The issue:**
**When I run detox in my Android hybrid app, the app launches but immediately closes.**

"react-native": "^0.57.8",
"detox": "^10.0.5",
"jest": "^24.0.0"

**I test the same configuration in a React Native app, and it works.**

I found this issue but it has been close without any change:
https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/720

**Android Emulator Log:**

> ```
> --------- beginning of crash
> ```
>
> 2019-01-30 11:17:00.862 5047-5081/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: com.wix.detox.manager
>       Process: com.example.ha.androidapp, PID: 5047
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
>           at com.wix.detox.ReactNativeSupport.getInstanceManager(ReactNativeSupport.java:63)
>           at com.wix.detox.ReactNativeSupport.waitForReactNativeLoad(ReactNativeSupport.java:117)
>           at com.wix.detox.ReactNativeCompat.waitForReactNativeLoad(ReactNativeCompat.java:33)
>           at com.wix.detox.DetoxManager.start(DetoxManager.java:72)
>           at com.wix.detox.Detox$1$1.run(Detox.java:133)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at com.wix.detox.Detox$1.run(Detox.java:136)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModulePath("index")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();
    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "MyReactNativeApp", null);

    setContentView(mReactRootView);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the device/emulator logs? What error did they give?

Comment: Andrew, I updated the question adding the log

Comment: There's an issue with non greenfield RN apps on Detox Android, it's a known issue and is in our roadmap to solve it.
https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/1093

Comment: It would actually be better if you report all the data you have in the Detox issue tracker (in the link above)